Would adding baking soda/powder help these crackers?
This is a sourdough discard recipe for crackers that I love the flavor of. When spread over a 9x13 inch baking sheet the crackers are thick and hard, when spread over a 10x15 inch sheet they are too delicate and break easily. Would adding 1/8 to 1/4 tsp baking soda (or baking powder) make a thicker cracker that was not so hard when spread over the 9x13 pan?
Crackers
1 cup (227g to 241g) sourdough starter, unfed/discard
4 tablespoons (57g) unsalted butter, melted
1/2 teaspoon to 3 teaspoons of your favorite seasoning(s) and/or seed(s)*
1/2 teaspoon table salt
Preheat the oven to 325°F with a rack in the middle. Line a baking sheet with a piece of parchment and set aside.
In a medium bowl, combine all the ingredients, stirring vigorously with a spatula until evenly combined.
Transfer the batter to the prepared pan and use a small offset spatula to spread it into a thin rectangle, about 11" x 15" in size. Sprinkle the top of the crackers with the toppings of your choice.
Bake the crackers for 15 minutes, then remove them from the oven, and use a pizza wheel or bench knife to cut the crackers into 1" to 1 1/2" squares (don't separate them, just cut them
Return the baking sheet to the oven and bake for an additional 35 to 45 minutes, rotating the pan halfway through, until the crackers in the middle are golden brown and firm to the touch.
Remove the crackers from the oven and allow them to cool completely on the baking sheet before serving.

not sure, but if the sourdough starter is still active, you might get the same effect by letting it rise before baking

It would be difficult to get baking powder/soda well-distributed in the wet mix. I let mine sit for 20-30 minutes after spreading it out, and I bake for about 20 minutes at 425°F.
